# Show that $|f(x)|≤1$ a.e

Tags: analysis

> Let $(\Omega ,A,\mu )$ be a measure space and $f,\,f_1,\ldots,\,f_n,\ldots$ measurable functions such that:
> $(1)$ $f_n \overset{\mu }{\longrightarrow}f$ and $(2)$ $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ for a.e. $x$ for all $n$. Show that $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for a.e. $x$.

What I have done so far:

$f_n \overset{\mu }{\rightarrow}f \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0:\mu (\left \{ x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon  \right \})\xrightarrow[]{n\rightarrow \infty }0$

$\forall n,\exists N \in \Omega : \mu (N)=0 \wedge\forall x \in \Omega \setminus N : |f_n(x)|\leq 1$

$|f_n (x)-f(x)|\leq |f_n(x)|-|f(x)| \leq 1 - |f(x)| $

But now I have no idea how I should continue...

Comment: $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq |f_n(x)|-|f(x)|$ is not true.

Comment: I've edited the post to clean up the presentation a bit. I tried as best as I could to maintain the OP's original intent; feel free to roll back the edit if it seems more unclear or if I entered something incorrectly.

Comment: Suggestion: Write down what it is that you want to prove. Compare this to the information that the problem gives to you and see if there are ways to implement the given information into the statement you want to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Study the set $$\mu (\left \{ x:|f(x)|\geq 1  \right \}).$$
How $|f| \leq |f_n-f|+|f_n|$
it follows that
$$ \left \{ x:|f(x)|\geq 1+2\varepsilon  \right \} \subset \{ x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon   \} \cup  \{ x:|f_n(x)|> 1   \}.$$
for small $\varepsilon$.Then
$$ \mu \left( \{ x:|f(x)|\geq 1+2\varepsilon  \right \}) \leq \mu \left( \{ x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon   \} \right) + \mu \left(  \{ x:|f_n(x)|>1   \} \right).$$
Now send $n$ to infinity and $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ to get the result.

Comment: Did you mean $\{x:|f(x)|\geq 1\}\subset\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon\}\cup \{x:|f_n(x)|\geq 1-\varepsilon\}$? It doesn't seem right either way.

Comment: I added an edit and fixed it.

Comment: If we send $n$ to infinity, $\mu(\{x:|f_n(x)|\geq 1-\varepsilon\})$ doesn't necessarily go to zero, since it can be the case that $f_n(x)=1$ for every $x \in \Omega$ for example.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary by definition of measure convergence, it can be $1/n.$

Comment: so if we send n to infinity the right one goes to 0 , but for the left one we have  $\mu \left( \{ x:|1-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon   \} \right)$ is this smaller than $\mu \left( \{ x:|1| +|-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon   \} \right)$ ? i'm sorry this is all very new for me and i don't really know what i am allowed to do here

Comment: when you talk on the left you are talking about $\mu \left( \{ x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon   \} \right)$? If so, it's because $f_n \overset{\mu }{\rightarrow}f$.

Comment: ah ok, so $\mu \left( \{ x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon   \} \right)$ is also going to 0 ?

Comment: Yes! exactly because $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure.

Comment: aaaah ok  and then $\{x:|f(x)|\geq 1\}\subset 0 \cup 0$ ? and this shows that $|f (x) | \geq 1$ ? a.e i forgot

Comment: no, you are confusing set inclusion with sum of measures. You have to pay more attention. If you are having difficulty understanding convergence in measure, I recommend reading Bartle's book: https://books.google.com.br/books?id=aE1YBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false  for example, see chapter 7.

Comment: @Ilovemath even if $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ it can be the case this term doesn't go to 0. For example, if $f_n(x)=1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ x \in \Omega$ then the term is always equal to $\mu(\Omega)$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ and $n \in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @JPMarciano a new edit was made, now it's clearer.

Comment: @Ilovemath It doesn't seem right yet for the same reason: $\mu(\{x:f_n(x)\geq 1\})=\mu(\Omega)$ when $f_n(x)=1$ for every $x$ and $n$.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of modifying the inclusion of sets as above.

Comment: Yeah, now it is ok! Sorry for being annoying.

Comment: no problem! math needs to be clear and correct!

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the following inequality:
$$|f| \leq |f_n| + |f - f_n|.$$